# When making a point feature a different point feature appears

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am digitizing a map and I have sample locations and station locations. The program (ArcMap10) worked fine until recently. Now when I try to add a sample it adds a station instead. Any ideas on how to fix this is much appreciated1

Comment: take a look at the [editing in ArcGIS 10](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/editing-in-arcgis10.pdf) document. It sounds like you need to set the correct layer in the Create Features dialog

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking the Properties of the layer you are editing to see whether on the Fields tab that particular field has its Default set to station.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Create Features' button on the Editor Toolbar, then select the feature class or subtype you want to work with.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_editing/01m500000002000000/